# Ошибка UnboundLocalError: local variable 'balance' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, telegram-bot

При прописке команды /profile выдаёт следующею ошибку:

> bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Имя персонажа: {message.from_user.first_name}\nДеньги персонажа:{balance}\nРепутация персонажа:{reput}")
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'balance' referenced before assignment

```
import telebot
import sqlite3
from random import randint

bot = telebot.TeleBot('1822313271:AAG2A4_0WmRtXpoounFEUn79vp4X_v_n2sk')


db = sqlite3.connect('server.db', check_same_thread=False)
cu = db.cursor()


cu.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    user_id INT,
    cash INT,
    rep INT
)""")
db.commit()




@bot.message_handler(commands=["reg"])
def echo_all(message):
    cu.execute(f"SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_id={message.from_user.id}")
    if cu.fetchone() is None:
        cu.execute(f"INSERT INTO user VALUES(?, ?)", (message.from_user.id, 0))
        db.commit()

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{message.from_user.first_name}, я успешно зарегистрировал тебя в Базе Данных!')

@bot.message_handler(commands=["help"])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"[Система]Все команды в игре:\nСистемные команды:\n/reg - открывает регистрацию персонажа\nИгровые команды:\n/profile - открывает профиль")


@bot.message_handler(commands=["profile"])
def send_profile(message):
    for i in cu.execute(f"SELECT cash FROM user WHERE user_id={message.from_user.id}"):
        balance = i[0]
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Имя персонажа: {message.from_user.first_name}\nДеньги персонажа:{balance}\n")




bot.polling()
```

Comment: Видимо `select` не сработал и переменная `balance` осталась не инициализированной.

Comment: @CrazyElf в таком случае, нужно удалить server.db?

Comment: Я не знаю, это зависит от логики работы вашей программы. Возможно, достаточно инициализировать переменную перед циклом: `balance = 0`